# what does "make pussy rain often" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I was watching a video of Conor McGregor vs Giant's Might (Hafþór Björnsson). In that video there is a song which has this weird line "**I'll make that pussy rain often**".

I found out that the song is often (Remix) called *By The Weekend*, which I had not heard about before.

I didn't understand what the singer wanted to mean by that phrase.
Since it is a slang internet could not provide me a decent information to understand this phrase.

Comment: See what [Urban Dictionary](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pussy%20rain) has to say: *When the rain is so light that you can survive without an umbrella, but people still have umbrellas up; pussy rain*.

Comment: I do not believe this is about light rain. "Pussy rain" has a sexual meaning.

Comment: Can anyone tell me why did I got down vote where as no one is sure what the answer is?

Comment: @Ghost - you probably got a downvote because 'pussy rain' is a very vulgar, rude, and crude expression.

Comment: Opps Sorry for that! Not familiar with rude expressions.It felt like I just asked to know about a name calling word like a child.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite appalled at seeing people have such discomfort in having to answer a simple question regarding sexuality. Someone mentioned people not having the "courage" for the same, which quite stuns me. I think all of them avoided answering at the presumption that this question is a joke. Maybe this is.

The phrase which you asked about is vulgar. I'm not sure if this is a site where you can get your questions having to do with sexuality solved. This site is not specifically meant for adults. So vulgar phrases should at best be avoided.

I don't intend to question the validity of your ignorance. But if you don't understand what that phrase means, then either you're not mature enough to be understanding what it does mean, or you are deficit in practicality - good or bad.

P***y means the female genital. Raining refers to its ejaculation when excited sexually.

Now if you have questions regarding how that happens or stuff, you should rather ask the internet, or just another forum (please don't).

If you're not at the proper age for knowing or dealing with this information, I urge you to deviate. If this was a joke, congratulations you had a good laugh, I hope it makes you the happiest person on earth. And if you're just less knowledgeable about colloquial English, it's not a problem. These aren't words you're supposed to know in the first place.

Edit:
I saw you were active on the mathematics space. Mathematicians have a pure heart. I trust your genuinity.

Comment: I would spend some time understanding why other people's discomfort enthralls you. Further down that road is Ted Bundy.

Comment: 'Pussy' is not just vulgar, it's misogynistic to many people.

Comment: No, drawing obvious conclusions based on your words does not make me a sociopath. You revised your words, so what I said no longer applies.

Comment: Uh, I didn't label you a sadistic rapist. Look up a few paragraphs, and you'll see exactly what I said -- "I would spend some time understanding why..." then I said, "Further down that road..." The meaning is plain. You wrote something and I counseled you to look inside and understand why. Then I warned you of the dangers of continuing to think that way. Then you changed what you said. How can my comments apply now? They can't, and for me to insist that they do would be silly.

Comment: Please refrain from vandalizing posts, even if they are your posts.

Answer (score 3):

It has to do with physiological changes during the sexual arousal of the human female.

Comment: Do you have any sources to back that up?

Comment: None that are reliable.

Comment: I never found this kind of English in medical science.May be I'm missing something.But the real thing is some American English slang are really hard to understand.
The Second fact is that there many physiological changes during "SeArous"..I still don't know which one was actually pointed by this phrase .

Comment: It is often difficult to understand foreign jokes. The formality of my response is a hint.

Comment: It's in lots of rap songs _I'm a make dat pussy rain_ etc.

Comment: @Ghost - rain is, above all, _wet_. Now do you understand?

Comment: @Ghost - "I never found this kind of English in medical science.". You won't. It's street 'argot' or dialect.

Comment: Now that's sounds clear.But one think i have to tell is that not all person talks in common street language.Even people talk in sophisticated English around me . I've asked them if they knew about this phrase.I guess I'm little too curious about everything and every word that catches my attention.

Comment: Still I don't think I deserve those down votes!

Comment: @Ghost By now, this question had been seen 61 times. I have hard time believing that at least half of those people did not know what it's about. Yet, only one person had the courage to put that into an answer. This somehow tells me — however strange it may seem — that this is sort of a taboo. Maybe not the topic itself, but _the representation of this topic in this specific subculture_ made some people feel that it is not a good fit for this website...

Comment: I searched for the lyrics, and it's obvious that the whole song is highly sexual in nature (and highly disrespectful to women).

Comment: @Levente - "This somehow tells me — however strange it may seem — that this is sort of a taboo." Why does it seem strange? Explicit talk about sexual matters is approaching a taboo boundary in any case. Using the word 'pussy' about women does this, and it also triggers another issue: misogyny. Remember Donald Trump describing sexual assault as "grabbing women by the pussy"? I am a little surprised that this explanation is needed.

Answer (score -2):

This is a complex construction with an unusual result: the speaker is going to make something else rain. The only other example of this result might be in some telling of the parable of Job, where Satan makes a cloud rain to soak Job and make him curse God.

The other meaning that this construction can take in the vernacular (and I don't know whether this meaning is intended in addition to or instead of the above) is for someone to (through force of will or some magical magnetism) summon something in such abundance that it the sudden influx of it would make it seem to be raining on the immediate area. The presence of "often" at the end of the phrase leaves me less certain that this secondary meaning is intended, as it would  a bit redundant. The use of "that" makes me think the phrase refers to unspecified—and yet specific—individual instances of genital response.

As others have said, many consider this term unacceptable as an anatomical reference and even more offensive when it reduces individuals' identities to descriptions of their private parts. This latter sense is an example of [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche), and since you're using a part of someone to describe them, an example of [objectification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objectification). When applied according to sex, this poor treatment is [sexism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexism) and since the word is often used to disparage women (or to use femininity itself for disparaging others), it is more specifically [misogyny](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misogyny). It may be also worth mentioning [hyperbole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbole) here, as the liquid volumes in question (rainfall vs. human secretion) are known by the speaker and audience to differ greatly and the obvious exaggeration is employed for emphasis.